# How to insert text labels to data points (not in the data) using panel.text() in a lattice plot

Tags: r, graphics, scatter-plot, lattice, textlabel

I created a scatterplot from the data (see rcode and data below). The **y-axis** shows the **mean rate of sapflow** measured from the xylem in trees during transpiration and the **x-axis** shows the **mean ambient temperature**.

Within the scatterplot, **5 points** are shown. Each point shows how mean temperatures affect mean rates of sapflow over a **5 month period** **(i.e. June-October)**.

**Problem**

The first column in the data frame (found below) is called "Date" and consists of 5 rows named **"June", "July", "August", "September", and "October"**.

My overall goal is to label the five data points (i.e. labeled from left to right - data point 1 to data point 5) in the lattice plot (shown below) with text labels denoting these 5 months (i.e. found in column 1 in the data frame provided below) but not to let the text overlap with the trend line so it is easy to read (see the lattice plot below):-

**For instance (see lattice plot below):**

1. Data Point 1 = labeled June;
2. Data Point 2 = labeled July;
3. Data Point 3 = labeled August;
4. Data Point 4 = labeled Septebmer;
5. Data Point 5 = labeled October;

In response, I created a vector called **Data_labels** and I tried to label the points in the lattice plot using panel.text() to insert the text labels onto the data points.

However, I keep on getting these types of error messages when using **panel.text()** in different combinations.

Would anyone be able to help? If so, I would be deeply appreciative

**Rcode**

```
 ##Produce the date labels for the plot
      Date_labels<-c("June", "July", 
                     "August", "September", 
                     "October")

##Produce lattice plot
xyplot(Mean_Sapflow~Mean_Temperature, 
               data=Summarised_new_mean_sapflow, 
               col="red",
               pch=19,
               xlab="Temperature (°C)",
               ylab=expression(paste("Sapflow Litres day"^{-1})),
               type=c('p', 'smooth'),                  col.line='blue',
               panel.text(0,0, labels=Data_labels))
```

**Error messages:**

```
       Error in grob(label = label, x = x, y = y, just = just, hjust = 
       hjust,  : 
       object 'Data_labels' not found
```

**Scatterplot**

[image]

**Data:**

```
    structure(list(Date = structure(c(3L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 4L), .Label = c("August", 
"July", "June", "October", "September"), class 
    = "factor"), Mean_Humidity = c(17.6073333333333, 
    21.8006451612903, 18.3896774193548, 14.822, 11.3486666666667), 
        Mean_Radiation = c(263.673333333333, 270.906451612903, 178.98064516129, 
        152.233333333333, 93.6), Mean_Temperature = c(70.5613333333333, 
        61.3306451612903, 71.7335483870968, 72.2136666666667, 81.743
        ), Mean_Sapflow = c(16.067, 23.3567741935484, 22.9416129032258, 
        19.3093333333333, 6.70066666666667)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
    -5L))
```

Comment: Typo? Change `data_labels` to `date_labels`?

Comment: basic plot: `xyplot(Mean_Sapflow~Mean_Temperature, 
        data=Summarised_new_mean_sapflow, 
        col="red", pch=19, col.line="blue",
        type=c('p', 'smooth'),
   panel=function(x, y,...){
   panel.xyplot(x, y, ...)
   panel.text(x, y, labels=Date_labels, pos=4)
   }
 )` , but I dont know how to properly dodge the labels

Comment: Thank you, this code worked perfectly.